# hover doesn't work on IE11 browser for angular custom pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, internet-explorer-11

I have tried several other ways like ng-bootstrap as well. all have the same issue of hovering between li elements. hover works only if I come out of the nav container and go back again. I have attached my code. can some help me what to edit on this.

```html
 <div class="col" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="span8">
            <nav id="pagination">
                <ul *ngIf="_dataSize != 0 && _pageSizeOptions.length > 0" class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled: currentPage === 1}">
                        <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(1)">First</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled: currentPage === 1}">
                        <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(currentPage - 1)">Previous</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item" *ngFor="let page of pages" [ngClass]="{active: currentPage === page}">
                        <a class="page-link page" (click)="setPage(page)">{{page}}</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled: currentPage === totalPages}">
                        <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(currentPage + 1)">Next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{disabled: currentPage === totalPages}">
                        <a class="page-link" (click)="setPage(totalPages)">Last</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I was able to fix with this block of css :  .page-link{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }

Comment: So you mean the issue can be fixed with the css you post in the comment? You could post it as an answer if you have solved the issue and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.